# View action open blank detail page for an order in adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, orders, order-grid

I get from a 3rd party orders that I save into **sales_flat_order**, **sales_flat_order_grid**, **sales_flat_order_payment** and **sales_flat_order_address**

I can see the orders I create into those table in order grid but when I click on view action I don't see any detail as the page is blank.

I don't Know if I have to insert information in other tables?

[image]

Enabling the error code for dev I have this hwen I try to enter to admin magento.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in <b>D:\wamp\www\magento1.9\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\View\Info.php</b> on line <b>161</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the row for billing Address was missing (thinking that we could only save shipping address if the Customer doesn't ask for billing). Adding this row I got perfect detail order dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer mode in your magento.
Open `index.php` in magento root directory and uncomment

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

After that please add:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

This way you will see real error. (You can find it in sourxe of the page at the end of the page).
Post it here and we will help you to find solution.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've edit my post. I've added the warning I've in the page. I don't know if this is the issue? I've added the code you tell me like this in index.php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); But for order I can see details for other orders isntalled with default magento shop but the one I insert have this problem

Comment: I've added the error in the post I found using the http request detail of ngrok

Comment: It looks like you do not have address object.
Check Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info::getAddressEditLink
If you will check app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\bro_solutions\sales\order\view\info.phtml , you will see two following rows:
<?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getBillingAddress())?>
<?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getShippingAddress())?>
So, I think you save only one address into sales_flat_order_address, but there should be two rows for each orders (billing and shipping)